# Constructor instantiate object from a Record<string,any>

Tags: json, typescript, constructor, record

I'm trying to create a constructor that assembly an object from a parameter that is a JSON-like, for exemple:

```
const inputData: Record<string,any> = {a:1, b:"hello"}

class MyClass {
    a:number;
    b:string;
    
    constructor(data:Record<string,any>){
        for(k in data){
            this[k] = data[k]
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot do this because `k` isn't something valid to be a 'key' of MyClass new instance.

Already have tried all sorts of combination with `typeof` `keyof` like:

```
constructor(data:Record<string,any>){
    type AllowedKeys = keyof typeof MyClass;
    for(k in data){
        const key:AllowedKeys = k as AllowedKeys;
        this[key] = data[key]
    }
}
```

But I receive the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> '"prototype"' can't be used to index type 'MyClass'.   Property 'prototype'
> does not exist on type 'MyClass'.(7053)

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow arbitrary keys, you can declare your class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    [index: string]: any; // <-- allow arbitrary keys

    a:number;
    b:string;
    
    constructor(data:Record<string,any>){
        for(k in data){
            this[k] = data[k]
        }
    }
}
```